# Babel How to ignore jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm using mocha with babel:register to test my react code.

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-register
```

In my react components (not the test), I'm using jquery with $ symbol and the test is complaining about $ is not a function. How can I ignore this?

The reason I'm doing this but not using `import $ from 'jquery'` is because rails has jquery bundled so I don't want to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling. You can set up jQuery or $ in global variable.

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
global.$ = jquery;
```